Cloudfront access to bucket without S3 bucket policy?
I am attempting to set up a Cloudfront distribution to an S3 bucket as I'm specifically attempting to set up a referer policy. The problem is that Cloudfront seems to be ignoring the bucket policy completely. I don't even have the Cloudfront policy set on this private S3 bucket, and yet I can still access all content through the Cloudfront distribution.
I've tried changing the settings between Origin Access Control as well as Origin Access Identity, but I'm not having any luck. The Cloudfront distibution continues to have direct access no mater the settings I've tried.
Am I missing something in the settings?

Are you saying that there is NO bucket policy, but CloudFront can access it? Where the objects uploaded with ACL=public?

@JohnRotenstein There is an existing bucket policy, but it has not be updated with the Cloudfront policy, and my organization has not used Cloudfront up to this point. No, the objects were not loaded with a public ACL.

@habib_101 CloudFront has no special access privileges to S3, so if CloudFront can access the content and you don't know why, that is a problem with your bucket configuration, not a problem with your CloudFront configuration.  CloudFront can't correctly be said to "ignore" a bucket's policy because CloudFront is always unaware of the bucket's policy.  CloudFront makes the request to the bucket, and the bucket allows or denies the request.  CloudFront never makes that decision on behalf of S3 – because it can't.  The nature of your problem is unclear from this question.

If CloudFront can read from the bucket, then either the Bucket Policy is permitting it, or the files have been uploaded with ACL=public.
